# Meaning of training loss and validation loss

Tags: conv-neural-network, mnist, loss

I'm using the following MNIST example: https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/docs/user/tutorial.rst

I read about the training and validation loss. I know that the validation loss represents the error of the validation image set after running them through the trained network, but what is the unit of this number? So what is the exact meaning of this number?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The loss function in the example you mentioned is a categorical cross entropy loss. Categorical cross entropy loss calculates the cross entropy loss for each class and returns the sum total.

cross entropy loss = - sigma(over all classes c) Yc . log(Pc) where Yc is the correct class labels and Pc is the predicted probabilities between 0 and 1. As you can notice, if for a class the label is 1 and predicted probability is small the cross entropy loss will be very high and vice versa.

The unit of [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) is the number of "bits" needed to identify an event drawn from the set, if a coding scheme is used that is optimized for an "unnatural" probability distribution q, rather than the "true" distribution p, given two probability distributions p and q.

In the context of deep learning, the loss is a scaler value that is back-propagated to reduce its value in the next iteration.